# Unable to access application properties in Spring application

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, properties-file

I've been looking through similar questions for some time now but can't seem to resolve this issue - which should be straight forward. I have a simple Java class which imports a CSV file into a PostgreSQL table. The class looks like this

```
@Component
public class CsvToDb {

    @Value( "${spring.datasource.url}" ) 
    String jdbcUrl;
    @Value( "${spring.datasource.username}" ) 
    String user;
    @Value( "${spring.datasource.password}" ) 
    String pass;

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getFormatterLogger(CsvToDb.class.getName());
    GetProperties prop = new GetProperties();
    String queryFile = "queries/sql-queries.properties";
    String import_csv = prop.getProperty(queryFile, "importCsv");

    public void importCsv(File file) throws Exception {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, user, pass);
        logger.info("Copying data rows from stdin...");
        CopyManager copyManager = new CopyManager((BaseConnection) con);
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        copyManager.copyIn(import_csv, fileReader );
        logger.info("CSV File imported to database");
    }
}
```

My problem is accessing the database credentials from the application property files, of which I have 3, for different environments - dev, test & production. The files are named like `application-{environment}.properties`. The environment gets passed into the application at runtime, using the option `-Dspring.profiles.active=%arg1%` currently in a windows bat script (although it will also be getting called in a shell script script on a Linux server also). I can see from the log output that all 3 database credentials are being picked up as `NULL`. If I hard code the credentials into this class, it works perfectly. An example of the contents of the application properties file looks like this

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://...:5432/...
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
```

I have the following property files in my resource folder: "`application-dev.properties`", "`application-test.properties`", "`application-production.properties`" & "`application.properties`". I currently have the same content in the "`application.properties`" file as what's in the "`application-dev.properties`" file, as a test to see if it was something to do with not picking up the profile specific property file. I'm also passing in "`dev`" in the command line when I run the bat file, and I can see from the log output, that it does tell me "`The following profiles are active: dev`"

Is there something I'm missing? Any pointers in the right direction as to how I can correctly access these values from my property files within this class would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The inputs you provided are not enough to troubleshoot the issue. Do you have "application.properties"?. It's already clear you have dev, QA, prod. As the part of analysing keep the same data source properties inside dev,QA and prod properties and other properties if any and check whether it's picking or not.

Comment: For completeness, I have the following properties files in my resource folder: "application-dev.properties", "application-test.properties", "application-production.properties" & "application.properties". I currently have the same content in the "application.properties" file as what's in the "application-dev.properties" file, as a test to see if it was something to do with not picking up the profile specific property file. I'm also passing in "dev" in the command line when I run the bat file, and I can see from the log output, that it does tell me "The following profiles are active: dev"

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that spring creates the CsvToDb object. Using "new CsvToDb()" will not work.

Also, you did not mention if this was a spring boot application but it looks like it to me based on the property names and properties files names. Spring boot can configure the Data Source object for you so that you don't have to manage the properties in your code.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/data.html#data.sql.datasource.configuration

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).